# Continued Fraction Expansion

Tags: continued-fractions, hypergeometric-function

While reading ["Gauss, Landen, Ramanujan, the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean, Ellipses, π, and the Ladies Diary
"](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~berndt/gausslandenmonthly.pdf) [p.602] from

$F\left( -\dfrac {1}{2},-\dfrac {1}{2};1;\lambda^{2}\right)=1+\dfrac {\lambda ^{2}}{4\left( 1+w \right) }$ ,

It is said that "it can be shown that $w$ has the continued fraction expansion"

$w=\dfrac {1}{3}\left\{ \dfrac {-\dfrac {3}{16}\lambda ^{2}}{1}+\dfrac {-\dfrac {3}{16}\lambda ^{2}}{1}+\dfrac {-\dfrac {3}{16}\lambda ^{2}}{1}+\dfrac {-\dfrac {11}{48}\lambda ^{2}}{1}+. . .\right\}$.

I haven't had much experience with hypergeometric functions or continued fractions so I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain how this step is possible in detail.

Comment: pretty confident it cannot be easy, and you say you lack background. It is probably in Whittaker and Watson  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker_and_Watson . Meanwhile, for your general purpose I can recommend (inexpensive) http://www.amazon.com/Neverending-Fractions-Introduction-Australian-Mathematical/dp/0521186498 , Shallit and Zudilin are well known experts